# Formatting back references in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, formatting, natbib, back-referencing

I would like to change the way the back references are shown in the bibliography, such that they are all shown within parentheses. So I would like to see

> (page x, y, z)

after my bibitems. This is what I think could be a starting point...

```
\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\backrefxxx}[3]{(page \hyperlink{page.#1}{#1})}
```

But obviously this yields

> (page x), (page y), (page z)

Comment: For those looking for how to create back-references without `hyperref`, consider using the package [`citeref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/citeref) (listed among the suggestions [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-backref.html), see also [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82397/how-can-i-install-citeref-via-tlmgr-from-texlive-2012), in particular the comments about licensing).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backref=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  backrefpage = {page},% originally "cited on page"
  backrefpages = {pages},% originally "cited on pages"
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.

\clearpage

Some more text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

And a brute-force solution for `natbib`/`backref`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\BR@backref}{\newblock}{\newblock(page~}{}{}
\patchcmd{\BR@backref}{\par}{)\par}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text \citep{A01,B02}.

\clearpage

Some more text \citep{A01}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, that solution works. Unfortunately am I using the natbib package (and would like to keep it that way) and that clashes with biblatex...

Comment: In `(pages 1, 2)`, is it possible to replace the round brackets with square brackets?

Comment: @pluton `\usepackage{xpatch}\xpatchbibmacro{pageref}{parens}{brackets}{}{}`

Comment: Does the backref link refer to the exact position of citation or to the whole page of citation?

Comment: And... what about using BibTeX and `pagebackreff` from `hyperref`?

Comment: The more recent question [“Formatting back references in bibliography (BibTeX)”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183702/1635) gives some `bibtex`/`hyperref`-based options (no `biblatex` required).

Comment: Hurray, I got reputation of 50 and can ask long-awaited question: @lockstep, how can I delete an extra space before numbers if I removed the word "pages" from my backref. (Now I have “A. Author. Alpha, 2001. [ 1,2]”, I want to remove space before 1.)

Comment: @homo_loquens You could have asked a separate (follow-up) question. ;-) Here's the answer: `\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{\iflistundef{pageref}{}{\printtext[parens]{\printlist[‌​pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}`. You may replace `parens` with `brackets`.

Comment: I would rather use the default `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}` just like that. Which gives `(Cited on pages 1, 2)`. Not redefining `backrefpage` and `backrefpages` as `(page 1, 2)`, since that might give the impression you are referring to pages in the referenced work, whereas you are referring to page locations in your own document.