# How can I install citeref via tlmgr from TexLive 2012?

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu

How can I install [`citeref`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/citeref) via `tlmgr` from TexLive 2012 in Ubuntu 12.10?
Why was `citeref.sty` dropped in Texlive 2012?

Comment: I assume it was dropped from TeXLive because the status of its license is uncertain, and it therefore defaults to [non-free](http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/licenses.noinfo.html).  As the link says, you should consider carefully whether you can/should use such software.

Comment: `citeref` is now available under a BSD license.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`citeref.sty` is available on CTAN as `<CTAN>/macros/latex/contrib/citeref/citeref.sty`; it's not on TeX Live because the file shows no licensing notice whatsoever, so a non free license must be assumed in order to comply with the guidelines on free software.

You can't use `tlmgr` for installing it; however it's easy to install it manually with the following shell commands

```
wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/citeref/citeref.sty
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/citeref
sudo cp citeref.sty /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/citeref
sudo mktexlsr
```

The first command can also be

```
curl -O http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/citeref/citeref.sty
```

Comment: I installed TexLive 2012 on Ubuntu 12.04 via the [backports PPA](http://askubuntu.com/a/163683/76565) and followed all your commands but it still won't find `citeref.sty` when I compile the document. Any thoughts?

Comment: `citeref` is now available under a BSD license.

Answer (score 0):

Current path for manually installed packages is `/usr/local/share/texmf/`, so based on egreg's post, proper commands are:

```
wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/citeref/citeref.sty
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/citeref
sudo cp citeref.sty /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/citeref
sudo mktexlsr
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What's the basis for your claim that the "[c]urrent path for manually installed packages is `/usr/local/share/texmf/`? Which TeX distribution do you have in mind? For sure, on a MacOS system with MacTeX installed, the directory `/usr/local/share/texmf/` is not defined by default. I'm curious why you don't mention either `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` or `~/texmf`.