# Formatting back references in bibliography [BibTeX]

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, babel, back-referencing

I'm using the option `pagebackref` in `hyperref` package and I get just the links list at the end of each reference name. It should print something like "Cited on page/s ", but I don't manage it even to do that.

My aim is to change some command to make it say that in Spanish, and I found it already considers Spanish in `backref.sty`, which is called by `hyperref`, I think... Reading `hyperref`, `backref`, `backrefx`'s documentation didn't help.

Any guess?

Related: [Formatting back references in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36307/36389)

Comment: It seems to work with the command `\backrefalt` redefinition in http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2009-November/013746.html , which is also mentioned in the `backrefx` documentation, although after some other code I didn't even try as I don't know very well how it works. Mine is a *trial and error* approach.

Comment: For those looking for how to create back-references without `hyperref`, consider using the package [`citeref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/citeref) (listed among the suggestions [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-backref.html), see also [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82397/how-can-i-install-citeref-via-tlmgr-from-texlive-2012), in particular the comments about licensing).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use:

```
\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{[{\tiny%
    \ifcase #1 Not cited.%
          \or Cited on page~#2.%
          \else Cited on pages #2.%
    \fi%
    }]}
```

I put this is in a `\tiny` font in between square brackets `[]`. Change to your own tastes:)

Comment: Tiny [ and ] or no one, I suposse. ;) And, why the `\relax`?

Comment: @Andrestand Yeah, I like the normal size brackets and tiny backrefs...no idea why I put the \relax in :)

Comment: ;) What I meant is that with that code my PDFLaTeX is printing a `normalsize` [ but a `tiny` ], as the second one is before the first }.

Comment: @Andrestand Sorry, you're right. I've corrected this.

Comment: If there are m,ore pages, this returns, for instance, Cited on pages 2, 3 and 4. I am writing in another language (portuguese), so I would like to change the word `and` to the portuguese word `e`. How can I do it?

Comment: @PedroG.Mattos The `and` comes from [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). Try using [babel](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) or asking a new question/.

Comment: I can't get this solution to work with the Tufte-Book class.  Any help is much appreciated!  I should mention that since the Tufte-Book class automatically loads hyperref, I had to include this as well:  \usepackage[hyperpageref]{backref}

Comment: How to adapt it for `\usepackage[backref=section]{hyperref}`? I receave `(document)`, instead of "section name", for example, as backref to `\cite{}` by using `[backref=section]`...

Answer (score 7):

For a similar scenario, I preferred using a more concise text and explain it at the beginning of the bibliography, rather than using `\tiny` (which looks bad here, especially inside normal-sized brackets).
Combining [Andrew's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183735/1340) with [`natbib`'s `\bibpreamble`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70953/1340) and some space before the actual reference list with `\bigskip`, I ended up with the following setup, to customize as needed:

```
% Add any needed options:
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}

% Customize list of backreferences.
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183735/1340
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
    \ifcase #1%
          \or [Page~#2.]%
          \else [Pages~#2.]%
    \fi%
    }
% Explain list of backreferences.
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70953/1340
\renewcommand{\bibpreamble}{%
  [Citing pages are listed after each reference.]%
  \par\bigskip}
```

Of course, one can customize that preamble text (and formatting) further. To move the prelude closer to the title, for now I've settled on the following—but I'm not sure such low-level tuning is good typography (the above looks safer), so YMMV:

```
\newcommand{\myBibPreambleText}{[Citing pages are listed after each reference.]}

\renewcommand{\bibpreamble}{%
  \vspace{-2 \bigskipamount}%
  \myBibPreambleText%
  \par \vspace{2 \bigskipamount}}
```

EDIT: instead of hacking vertical spacing like that, it's probably more robust (typographically) to modify `\bibsection` to add a ["subtitle"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69561/1340), so that TeX computes the appropriate position. I can do this with the following code, where I've added `\\ {\normalsize\mdseries \myBibPreambleText}` to the definition of `\bibsection` which was in use for me, unless I load the `tocbibind` package, which rewrites the relevant code.

```
\newcommand{\myBibPreambleText}{[Citing pages are listed after each reference.]}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{
  \chapter*{\bibname \\ {\normalsize\mdseries \myBibPreambleText}}
  \@mkboth {\MakeUppercase {\bibname }}{\MakeUppercase {\bibname }}
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I have tried to make the above solutions work with the Tufte-Book class using bibtex but to no avail. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: @Steven I forget the details of this answer, but `\renewcommand` tells me this solution was patching the internals of the involved packages. To adapt the answer, somebody probably needs to look at how the Tufte-Book class changes the bibliography code. If you need help with that, I recommend a new question with a MWE :-)

Comment: I have done what you suggested.  See:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656431/back-referencing-from-bibliography-using-tufte-book-class-bibtex    Thank you!