# How to set Italian as language for hyperref's backref option in moderncv

Tags: hyperref, moderncv, multibib, backref

I'm using `moderncv` package by using some `\cite{}` in the document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
...
\usepackage{multibib}
\begin{document}
\section{\textbf{\textcolor{gray}{Section 1}}}
Text \cite{demo}
...
...
...
\section{\textbf{\textcolor{gray}{Section 2}}}
Other text \cite{demo}
...
\section{\textbf{\textcolor{gray}{Riferimenti}}}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{riferimenti}
\end{document}
```

and I customized the `moderncv.cls` file by adding backreferences, in this way:

```
\RequirePackage[unicode, pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
  %%%%  CUSTOM backref COMMAND: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183735
  \renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
  \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{[{%
      \ifcase #1 Nessuna citazione%
            \or Cit. a pagina~#2%
            \else Cit. alle pagine~#2%
      \fi%
      }]}
```

Now the problem is that the E conjunction (for the pages) remains in English, instead of in Italian, when the \cite{} command is repeated in different pages. So I get:

> [1] ... [Cit. alle pagine 1 **and** 3]

Note the 'AND' (in English) instead of 'E' (in Italian) as conjunction.

I think the cause is to be found in the file `backref.sty`, where different languages seem to be supported, but not the Italian:

```
...
\def\backrefenglish{%
  \def\backrefpagesname{pages}%
  \def\backrefsectionsname{sections}%
  \def\backrefsep{, }%
  \def\backreftwosep{ and~}%
  \def\backreflastsep{, and~}%
}
\def\backrefgerman{%
  \def\backrefpagesname{Seiten}%
  \def\backrefsectionsname{Abschnitte}%
  \def\backrefsep{, }%
  \def\backreftwosep{ und~}%
  \def\backreflastsep{ und~}%
}
\def\backreffrench{%
  \def\backrefpagesname{pages}%
  \def\backrefsectionsname{sections}%
  \def\backrefsep{, }%
  \def\backreftwosep{ et~}%
  \def\backreflastsep{ et~}%
}
\def\backrefspanish{%
  \def\backrefpagesname{p\'aginas}%
  \def\backrefsectionsname{secciones}%
  \def\backrefsep{, }%
  \def\backreftwosep{ y~}%
  \def\backreflastsep{ y~}%
}
\def\backrefbrazil{%
  \def\backrefpagesname{p\'aginas}%
  \def\backrefsectionsname{se\c c\~oes}%
  \def\backrefsep{, }%
  \def\backreftwosep{ e~}%
  \def\backreflastsep{ e~}%
}
\def\backrefafrikaans{%
  \def\backrefpagesname{bladsye}%
  \def\backrefsectionsname{afdelings}%
  \def\backrefsep{, }%
  \def\backreftwosep{ en~}%
  \def\backreflastsep{ en~}%
}%
...
\BR@DeclareLang{english}{english}
\BR@DeclareLang{american}{english}
\BR@DeclareLang{australian}{english}
\BR@DeclareLang{british}{english}
\BR@DeclareLang{canadian}{english}
\BR@DeclareLang{newzealand}{english}
\BR@DeclareLang{UKenglish}{english}
\BR@DeclareLang{USenglish}{english}
\BR@DeclareLang{german}{german}
\BR@DeclareLang{ngerman}{german}
\BR@DeclareLang{austrian}{german}
\BR@DeclareLang{naustrian}{german}
\BR@DeclareLang{french}{french}
\BR@DeclareLang{acadian}{french}
\BR@DeclareLang{canadien}{french}
\BR@DeclareLang{frenchb}{french}
\BR@DeclareLang{francais}{french}
\BR@DeclareLang{spanish}{spanish}
\BR@DeclareLang{brazil}{brazil}
\BR@DeclareLang{brazilian}{brazil}
\BR@DeclareLang{afrikaans}{afrikaans}
...
```

I so tried to add:

```
...
\def\backrefafrikaans{%
  \def\backrefpagesname{bladsye}%
  \def\backrefsectionsname{afdelings}%
  \def\backrefsep{, }%
  \def\backreftwosep{ en~}%
  \def\backreflastsep{ en~}%
}
\def\backrefitalian{%
  \def\backrefpagesname{pagine}%
  \def\backrefsectionsname{sezioni}%
  \def\backrefsep{, }%
  \def\backreftwosep{ e~}%
  \def\backreflastsep{ e~}%
}%
...
\BR@DeclareLang{afrikaans}{afrikaans}
\BR@DeclareLang{italian}{italian}
...
```

but without success.

How to make the choice for the Italian language?
The only thing that worked has been to change `\def\backrefenglish` with:

```
\def\backrefenglish{%
  \def\backrefpagesname{pagine}%
  \def\backrefsectionsname{sezioni}%
  \def\backrefsep{, }%
  \def\backreftwosep{ e~}%
  \def\backreflastsep{, e~}%
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great, solved: I just have to use the new created command `\backrefitalian` like so:

```
\section{\textbf{\textcolor{gray}{Riferimenti}}}
\backrefitalian
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{riferimenti}
```

How to make Italian language be added to `hyperref` package?

**Edit:**
I opened a [new post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/675747/69637) to discuss a rearrangement of the code presented here. Thank you

Comment: Probably by opening an issue or, better, proposing a PR at https://github.com/latex3/hyperref

Comment: Thank you, @Rmano

Comment: Pull request done: https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/pull/274#issue-1590567926