# Customization and multilingual support for \backrefalt for hyperref's backref with moderncv

Tags: hyperref, moderncv, translations, customize, backref

Referring to my [previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675648/how-to-set-italian-as-language-for-hyperrefs-backref-option-in-moderncv), I reopen now the topic saying that I performed a [pull request](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/pull/274#issue-1590567926) on GitHub  (as suggested by @rmano, whom I thank, in the comments), to implement the Italian language support, but I also rearranged the previous code, inserting the customization of the backreferences directly in the definition of the commands `\backrefenglish`, `\backrefgerman`, `\backreffrench`, `\backrefspanish`, `\backrefbrazil`, `\backrefafrikaans`, `\backrefitalian`, like so:

```
\def\backrefenglish{%
  \def\backrefpagesname{pages}%
  \def\backrefsectionsname{sections}%
  \def\backrefsep{, }%
  \def\backreftwosep{ and~}%
  \def\backreflastsep{, and~}%
  \renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}% for backref < 1.33 necessary
  \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{[{%
    \ifcase ##1 No citations%
      \or Cited in page~##2%
      \else Cited in pages~##2%
    \fi%
  }]}%
}
\def\backrefitalian{%
  \def\backrefpagesname{pagine}%
  \def\backrefsectionsname{sezioni}%
  \def\backrefsep{, }%
  \def\backreftwosep{ e~}%
  \def\backreflastsep{ e~}%
  \renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}% for backref < 1.33 necessary
  \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{[{%
    \ifcase ##1 Nessuna citazione%
      \or Cit. a pagina~##2%
      \else Cit. alle pagine~##2%
    \fi%
  }]}%
}
```

It would be necessary to extend the translation of the following 3 sentences in the current languages (german, french, spanish, brazil, afrikaans), if you can contribute in my branch `backref-multilingual-implemented` on [GitHub](https://github.com/ChemBioScripting/hyperref/tree/backref-multilingual-implemented):

1. *No citations*
2. *Cited in page*
3. *Cited in pages*

The code works, generating the Italian or English version of the custom `\backrefalt` command, based on `\backrefenglish` or `\backrefitalian` used command inside `\begin{document}`, before `\bibliographystyle` (as shown in the [previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/675649/69637)), but it is necessary to comment out the `\backrefenglish` command after `\BR@DeclareLang{italian}{italian}`, in the `backref.sty` file of `hyperref` package, making it explicit instead with the one in the desired language (`\backrefenglish`, `\backrefgerman`, `\backreffrench`, `\backrefspanish`, `\backrefbrazil`, `\backrefafrikaans` or `\backrefitalian`) inside `\begin{document}`, before `\bibliographystyle`. Maybe the written code could be made cleaner, considering also a `backref` to `sections` instead of `pages`. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure that the rearrangement is a good idea. Wouldn't that affect existing documents which set e.g backrefalt?

Comment: Hello @UlrikeFischer, for now I made a copy of the `hyperref`'s `backref.sty` file and I put it in the same folder as my `.tex` document making the above changes and it works. I'm asking if the code can be written in such a way to make it global with the possibility to contemplate a similar scenario of customization with multilingual translation of back-references. It would be nice, I think

Comment: sorry no, by defining \backrefalt for all languages you are clearly changing the behaviour. Currently backref tests if \backrefalt is used or not. So I don't think that I would accept a pull request which changes that.