# Alternative to pagebackref

Tags: hyperref

Because of some conflicts with my settings I cannot use hyperref. Assume that I am only interested with the pagebackref feature of this package. Is there a package or a direct solution which does the same job?

Comment: backref package doesn't depend on hyperref as far as I recall (even though distributed with it)

Comment: Thank you, your comment solved my problem. Should I remove this question?

Comment: Nah leave it, I've made it an answer and then you can give me a point or two for writing the package:-)

Comment: There is also `citeref.sty`. Relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82397/8666

Answer (score 3, accepted):

backref package doesn't depend on hyperref as far as I recall (even though distributed with it)