# Link from bibliography to first occurrence

Tags: bibliographies, pdftex, hyperref

Is there a way to make bibliography entries link back to the first instance of citation?

For example, say on page 5 I have text like:

> Foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar [1].

and the respective bibliography entry:

> [1] Best Author. "Awesome article". In: Credible Journal (2015).

I'd like to be taken to page 5 when I click on [1] in the bibliography entry, much the same way clicking on [1] on page 5 takes me to the bibliography entry.

Is this possible?

I'm currently using pdflatex with hyperref and biblatex with biber for backend.

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36307/formatting-back-references-in-bibliography?

Comment: Thanks, this basically answers my question. I found a similar question, but instead of doing `\usepackage[backref=true]{biblatex}` it suggested adding an option to `hyperref`, and that didn't work for me.

Comment: I would still be interested if anyone know how to add the link to the first page to the reference number without printing `(cit. on p. 5)`.

Comment: Very related (possible duplicate, even): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164269/35864

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to call the `hyperref`package before `biblatex`. 
And you would have to use the following options in your biblatex configuration "backref=true, pagebackref=true".

More infos about hyperlinks are available [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks)

Comment: `hyperref` need not be loaded before `biblatex`. It is perfectly acceptable to load `hyperref` after `biblatex` (just don't load it in`\AtBeginDocument`). Note that the OP is not looking for the usual `backref` option (there is no `pagebackref` *option* for `biblatex`, using it will cause an error), instead they want something slightly less intrusive.

Comment: I usually use apabackref instead of pagebackref but since the example isn't in apa I adapted