# Biblatex error: Incompatible backref package

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, back-referencing

I am using shareLaTeX with the XeLaTeX compiler. Still new to the Latex so I cannot resolve the problem...

The only problem is that backref does not work.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{mystyle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[hidelinks,pagebackref,hyperindex=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
style=ieee,
bibencoding=ascii
backref=true
% style=alphabetic
% style=reading
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}

\begin{document}

Text \cite{alpha}, bla bla bla \cite{bravo}.

\printbibliography[title={Referências Bibliográficas}, notkeyword=carta]

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Referências Cartográficas}

\printbibliography[title={Referências Cartográficas}, keyword=carta]

\end{document}
```

So I get the error:

```
Package biblatex Error: Imcompatible package 'backref'.
```

I've tried to use this fix:
[Formatting back references in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36307/formatting-back-references-in-bibliography)

But for some reason, it does not work for me.

Comment: Remove option `pagebackref` and load package `hyperref` after package `biblatex`. The document in the question cannot be tested, because of the private class and missing bibliography data.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek This did in fact resolve the problem with the compatibility issue, however I still do not have back references available in the bibliography.

Comment: HeikoOberdiek's suggestions should help. But if your `mystyle.cls` does weird things and loads other packages that we don't see you might have to do something else. Does `mystyle.cls` load `backref`?

Comment: Hello @moewe. The suggestion of HeikoOberdiek did work in solving the compatibility issue. But there is no backref working...

Comment: Well, the option `backref=true` turns on the backref, unless something is terribly wrong. Since we can't test your MWE (we don't have your class, `.bib` files etc.) and you don't show us the output you get, we can only guess. Please give us something more to go on.

Comment: I'll try to upload what I've got and also the .bib file. For the class is a bit more complex since it uses a proprietary class from the university. But I've already checked that and there is nothing there that could interfere with this issue. I have a bunch of active packages, maybe it has something to do with it. I'll try to upload what I've got. Thank you.

Comment: Please try to make the example as minimal as possible. Ideally you would check if you can reproduce the problem with another class, `article` say. If not you would search through the code of the custom class you used to identify the problematic lines.

Comment: Sorry @moewe. I didn't had the time to do it. Tomorrow I'll update the question. Thank you.

Comment: Any news here? I still cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: It's not working for me either.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek This also worked for me, thanks.