# Incompability of backref with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, citing, koma-script, back-referencing

This question might be related to [Biblatex error: Incompatible backref package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383054/biblatex-error-incompatible-backref-package) but has no solution and did not provide an example of document.

Running the following

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[natbib=true,style=ieee]{biblatex}

\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chap 1}
Some text\cite{greenwade93}. 


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Gives me the error:

> See the biblatex package documentation for explanation. Type  H   for immediate help.  ...
>
> l.8 \begin{document}
> The 'backref' package and biblatex are incompatible.

What is the right way to use backref? I also tried `\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}` and got a similar error. I don't get what is not compatible with it.

Comment: `biblatex` offers its own back referencing mechanism. You could try adding `backref=true` to its package options.

Comment: @leandriis that works, any idea on how to change the way the backref is formatted in the bibliography?

Comment: Depends on what part you want to alter specifically. Some options are listed starting on page 52 of the [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was to quick to post this question but the answer is relatively simple (see comments). Biblatex has its own way to do it:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[natbib=true,style=ieee,backref=true]{biblatex}%<--- add here 

\usepackage{hyperref}%<---- instead of here
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chap 1}
Some text\cite{greenwade93}. 


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

One can also add

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  backrefpage={Cited on page},
  backrefpages={Cited on pages}
}
```

to replace "Cit. on pp" by another string.