# Using Tufte-book document class with bibliography backref

Tags: tufte, backref

I would like to have back references in my Tufte style document.

I first created a minimal working example that creates back references using the article document class, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36307/formatting-back-references-in-bibliography) which worked as expected.

I then attempted to make minimal adjustments to make it work with the Tufte document class as well. This did not work. I observed that when running `pdflatex`, I got a warning:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Option `backref' has already been used,
(hyperref)                setting the option has no effect on input line 3.
```

I am assuming that `hyperref` is loaded by the Tufte style and sets the `backref` option, which then prevents me from changing it.

What can I do to make back references work with the Tufte document class?

Here is my example of successfully creating back references with the article class:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\BR@backref}{\newblock}{\newblock[page~}{}{}
\patchcmd{\BR@backref}{\par}{]\par}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

I cite a book~\cite{key}.

I cite that book again~\cite{key}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio.bib}

\end{document}
```

It produces this output which does contain the back reference `[page 1]`:

[image: output with back ref]

Here is my attempt to convert it into something compatible with Tufte:

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified]{tufte-book}

\hypersetup{backref=page}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\BR@backref}{\newblock}{\newblock[page~}{}{}
\patchcmd{\BR@backref}{\par}{]\par}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

I cite a book~\cite{key}.

I cite that book again~\cite{key}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio.bib}

\end{document}
```

This produces a document with three pages, correctly using the Tufte margin citations, but the backward page reference is missing, which makes sense, since the warning said I could not reset the `backref` option.

[image]

Here is my bibliography file in case it is relevant:

```
@book{key,
    author={Some Author},
    title={Title},
    publisher={Publisher},
    year={2001}
}
```

I am using `pdflatex` and `bibtex` from the command line to build my documents.

Comment: Help? Anybody? :(

Comment: Did you ever figure this issue out?  I am using the Tufte Book Class and would like to use back references as well!

Comment: sadly, no, I was not able to find a solution.

Comment: I finally figured out all my issues with the  great help  of this online community.  Check out my MWE at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659525/tufte-latex-missing-periods-in-biblatex-entry/659538#659538