# tufte-latex: missing periods in biblatex entry

Tags: biblatex, tufte, tufte-book

I don't know why the period is missing after the DATE and after the URLDATE in the bibliography entry in this MWE. Any guidance and or solution is much appreciated!

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}

\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,nobib,nohyper]{tufte-book}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,hyperindex=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=teal]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[
style=verbose,
autocite=footnote,
sorting=nty,
citecounter=true,
citetracker=true,
backref=true,
backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\setlength\bibitemsep{0.5\baselineskip}
\addbibresource{HSFSS-BIBLATEX.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@footnotetext}%
{\color@begingroup}
{\color@begingroup\toggletrue{blx@footnote}}
{}
{}
\makeatother
%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\sidecitehelper}[\bibfootnotewrapper]
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
%
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\sidecite{D<>{}O{}om}{%
    \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn \__sct_wrapper:nn ##1 ##2 {\mkbibparens{##2}}}
    {\cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn \__sct_wrapper:nn ##1 ##2 {\sidenote[][##1]{##2}}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#3}
        {\__sct_wrapper:nn{#1}{\sidecitehelper[#2]{#4}}}
        {\__sct_wrapper:nn{#1}{\sidecitehelper[#2][#3]{#4}}}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
\makeatletter
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname if@capstart\expandafter\endcsname
    \csname iftrue\endcsname
    \global\let\@currentHref\hc@currentHref
    \else
    \hyper@makecurrent{\@captype}%
    \fi
    \@ifundefined{NR@gettitle}{%
        \def\@currentlabelname{#2}%
    }{%
        \NR@gettitle{#2}%
    }%
    \par\addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}{%
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}%
    }%
    \begingroup
    \toggletrue{blx@footnote}%
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
    \@setminipage
    \fi
    \@tufte@caption@font\@tufte@caption@justification%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname if@capstart\expandafter\endcsname
    \csname iftrue\endcsname
    \global\@capstartfalse
    %\@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces#3}%
    \noindent\csname fnum@#1\endcsname: \ignorespaces#3%
    \else
    %\@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{%
    \noindent\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:
    \ignorespaces
    \ifHy@nesting
    \expandafter\hyper@@anchor\expandafter{\@currentHref}{#3}%
    \else
    \Hy@raisedlink{%
        \expandafter\hyper@@anchor\expandafter{%
            \@currentHref
        }{\relax}%
    }%
    #3%
    \fi
    %}%
    \fi
    \par
    \endgroup
}
%
\renewcommand\@footnotetext[2][0pt]{%
    \marginpar{%
        \hbox{}\vspace*{#1}%
        \def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
        \reset@font\footnotesize%
        \@tufte@margin@par% use parindent and parskip settings for marginal text
        \vspace*{-1\baselineskip}\noindent%
        \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
            \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark%
        }%
        \color@begingroup%
        \toggletrue{blx@footnote}%
        \@makefntext{%
            \ignorespaces#2%
        }%
        \color@endgroup%
    }%
}%
\makeatother
%
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \patchcmd\@floatboxreset
    {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
        \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
    {}
    {}
    {\blx@err@patch{float}}}
\makeatother
%
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}
{%
    \iflistundef{pageref}
    {\printtext{(\autocap{n}o citation in the text.)}}
    {
        \printtext{\autocap{c}ited \arabic{citecounter} time\ifnumgreater{\value{citecounter}}{1}{s}{}}%
        \setunit{\addspace}
        \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
        {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
        {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
        \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}
    }
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    backrefpage  = {on page},
    backrefpages = {on pages},
}
\begin{document}
In this scenario the potato acts like a pesticide, killing the Colorado potato beetle.\sidecite<0.7in>[][]{BtPotato}
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[type=online,heading=subbibliography,title={Internet Sources}]
\end{document}
```

.BIB file:

```
@online{BtPotato,
    author = {contributors SourceWatch},
    title = {{"Colorado Potato Beetle Resistant Bt Potato"}\textit{ SourceWatch}},
    date = {2012},
    url = {https://www.sourcewatch.org/index.php?title=Colorado_Potato_Beetle_Resistant_Bt_Potato&oldid=583413},
    urldate = {2022-08-22}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}
```

the `\setunit{\addspace}\newblock` before the URL block forces a single space to appear before the URL. To get back a normal unit separator (period in your case), use `\newunit\newblock` instead.

```
\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}
```

---

The space before the "cited x times on ..." block is controlled by `\bibpagerefpunct` whose default setting is `\addspace` (because `biblatex`'s default settings have this block in parentheses), you can try

```
\renewcommand*{\bibpagerefpunct}{\addperiod\space}
```

Comment: That worked.  Thank you!