# Clickable references in the bibliography that jump to text

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

Which package can I use to make the references in the bibliography clickable to jump from the bibliography to their first citation in the text/or to all their citations in the text (if it possible to list out all the pages where the citations occur) ?

The `hyperref` package does the work in the reverse direction, from the citation to the reference in the bibliography.
I would like a package or an option for `hyperref` that allows to jump from the reference in the bibliography to the text.

Comment: Have you tried `backreference`? Please show a short compilable TeX code building your bibliography and do not forget to add two bib entries to your question too.

Comment: Thank you @Mensch, by rewording my question thanks to your keyword I found a solution here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36307/formatting-back-references-in-bibliography

Comment: A played around with back references. The best thing I achieved was a line of page numbers where they appear. The problem is that you may reference the same source from different places in your document. To which of these shall the title link? If you can ensure that only one position is linked to each source, it should be possible with biblatex.