# biblatex: Customise formatting of back-references

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, back-referencing

I would like minimal back-references, i.e., I would like

> A. N. Other. 2001. *The mother of all breakthroughs*. World 3:141-592. 1.

instead of

> A. N. Other. 2001. *The mother of all breakthroughs*. World 3:141-592. (Cited
> on page 1.)

The reason is that repeating "Cited on" seems unnecessary (it can be explained once) and in long bibliographies, it can add quite a few short lines (in my case, it adds nearly half a page).

The following MWE is adapted from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36308/18181).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backref=true]{biblatex-chicago}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  backrefpage = {},% originally "cited on page"
  backrefpages = {},% originally "cited on pages"
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
 author = {Author, A.},
 year = {2001},
 title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
 author = {Buthor, B.},
 year = {2002},
 title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.
\clearpage
Some more text \autocite{A01}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The bibliography it produces looks like this:

[image]

How do I (a) get the parentheses to disappear and (b) remove the space before the first page reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the bibmacro `pageref`. The original definition can be found in [`biblatex.def` (ll. 2949-2956 in v3.19)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/24a94f8f608872e11d259d7c581fc90ea76542a5/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L2949-L2956).

Setting bibstrings to empty strings will usually not result in satisfactory output, since the styles generally assume that bibstrings produce output so that spurious space or punctuation appears.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backref=true]{biblatex-chicago}

\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text \autocite{sigfridsson,worman}.
\clearpage
Some more text \autocite{sigfridsson}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```