Reconstructing Custom Bibliography formatting from image with bibtex
I am writing my bachelors thesis and the institute didn't provide a decent LaTeX template, only some PhD thesis that I can use as a reference. Luckily I found some of the old code on one of the network drives, but as the thesis is from 2015, it does not compile anymore in the way it is written. I have fixed most of it, but I am still struggling with the bibliography.
It has this styling



where 1, 3-6, 173 are articles, 2 is a @misc,  117-119 are books and 172 is a phd thesis.
Of course they are not in that order in the bibliography, I just took some screenshots of all different entry types.
The numbers behind the actual infos (red) are the pages that the entry is cited on, which is very helpful as this way one can easily see which source was important as those are cited more often, or which was cited in which section (i.e. introduction, theoretical background, analysis,...). I already have that working. What doesn't work is the correct displaying of the infos themselves.
Here is the extract from the style.bst concerning the relevant options (I think):
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { %journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      format.bla output
      eid empty$
        %{ format.vol.num.pages link_it output }
        { format.pages output}
        { format.vol.num.eid output }
      if$        
        
        format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      eid empty$
        { format.pages output }
        { format.eid output }
      if$
    }
  if$


%  format.issn output
  format.doi output
%  format.url output
%  new.block
%  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.isbn link_it output
%  format.doi output
%  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  title howpublished new.block.checkb
  format.title output
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished output
  format.date output
  format.issn output
  format.url link_it output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}

FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  "PhD thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}

Can someone help me figure out what I have to change in order for it to output the displayed style? I would also be happy if someone pointed me to a way to achieve this using biblatex instead of bibtex, but I read that it is very difficult to convert a .bst-file into useable biblatex.

Is there an actual need to replica this old thesis bibliography style? If not, then this seems like a waste of learning time (I mean this in a friendly way). Instead, make yourself familiar with the current biblatex approach.

@Kuehner thank you for your comment. I understand that you mean it in a friendly way, and I suppose it is strictly speaking not necessary to reconstruct it. But as far as my research went, bibtex is still used very much, and as I was able to find the old .bst style file, I thought that I could at least learn something from it. I would gladly take the biblatex approach if I was able to conserve the features, namely the correct linking of the doi and the “cited on page #” feature, while of course having all necessary and correct information on the source.

Some years ago I made a small video tutorial about the first steps with biblatex: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYvS52511oQ&list=PL-Wl6F3zpJVwcDHK2rg9bDEEMjo70zp87. "Correct linking of the doi" and the “cited on page #” feature (= backref) is available in biblatex.

@Kuehner do you know a website where I can upload/insert a .bib entry and have a fast compiling preview of different citation styles so that I can find a similar one?

See my answer :)


@Kuehner do you know a website where I can upload/insert a .bib entry
and have a fast compiling preview of different citation styles so that I can find a similar one?

Here is a starting point, you can play with the style = ... part. See biblatex-examples.bib on CTAN for the contents of the example database.
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
 % style = alphabetic, % <-- Uncomment
 % style = numeric, % <-- Uncomment
 style = authoryear, % <-- Uncomment
 backref = true,
]{biblatex}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36307
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  backrefpage = {page},% originally "cited on page"
  backrefpages = {pages},% originally "cited on pages"
}

% example database comes with biblatex
% see https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\cite{kastenholz} 

\cite{aristotle:physics}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17128
%\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}



Thank you very much, I will look into this.
